# How to upload an OTF font onto Behance.com platform?

Tags: fonts, behance

How do you upload a font (*.otf) onto the Behance platform (for personal use / attribution required)?

When I attempt to upload the file a message box appears with a list of extensions (which does not include the .otf font extension).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot upload font files to Behance. They only support uploads for Images, Videos, and Audio.

See Behance FAQ

https://help.behance.net/hc/en-us/sections/205069127-Supported-Formats